# Dynamically pull Facebook videos into an external page

Tags: jquery, .net, facebook

If you look at something like http://www.facebook.com/subway/videos, there is a wall of videos. I'd like to somehow grab all of these to display on another site; as this page is updated, so will my page. Is this possible? If so, where do I start?

Ideally any methods using jQuery or .NET would be fantastic, but my request is probably quite large so any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to get the page ID from Facebook API and then get the page's videos from the same API.

Try to do that below.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageName = "subway";

// Gets the page ID
$.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/" + pageName, function(data) {
   pageId = data.id;

   // Get JSON array of videos
   $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner=" + pageId, function(videos) {
    $.each(videos.data, function(ix, el) {
        var title = el.title;
        var description = el.description;
        var thumb = el.thumbnail_link;
        var embedPlayer = el.embed_html;

        // Do your html stuff here
        $("body").append("<div>" + title + "<br/>" + embedPlayer + "</div><br/><br/><hr/>");        
    });
   });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just had to add

`embedPlayer =  embedPlayer.replace("https://graph.facebook.com", "https://www.facebook.com");`

after `var embedPlayer = el.embed_html;`

Comment: I tried this example one year ago and it returned `facebook.com` domain. Maybe they changed the main domain for the player. Anyway, it will be nice to check the root domain of `embedPlayer` variable and replace it by the correct. Thank you for your comment!